# Will I get full credit for "Defend the Train" objectives if I freeze it?

Tags: into-the-breach

I'm on a *Defend the Train* mission with the *Frozen Titans*  and it occurs to me that freezing the train would be a great way to defend it. It gets some protection from damage, and I don't need to worry about it slamming into any enemies with its movement. I've also got the *Ice Generator* upgrade which freezes a large area of the map, so I could easily freeze all the enemies, plus the train, which would go a long way towards securing my success in this mission. However, I'm not sure if I'll actually get credit for defending the train if I freeze it on turn 1, and it never reaches the other side of the map.

**Can I freeze the train and still get full credit for the *Defend the Train* objective?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes.** I just tested this in a mission by freezing the train on turn 1, and I got full credit for saving the train:

[image]

As far as I can tell the "Defend the train" objective is based purely on if the train takes damage, it doesn't actually need to reach the other side of the map.